# FaceBook stopped scraping the og:image tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This worked just fine a few days ago. Now, FaceBook refuses to fetch the image when I paste the link in the website (title & desc ARE fetched). It worked just fine when sharing via Google Plus (all info fetched).

I'm trying to share a link from my website via my website's FaceBook page.

http://mentatul.com/2016/08/17/is-yoga-really-an-entry-drug-to-buddhism

I've always had some warnings in FaceBook's sharing debugger so I don't know if this is some breaking change they added. One of the warnings now is "Share App ID Missing". You can see their report here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmentatul.com%2F2016%2F08%2F17%2Fis-yoga-really-an-entry-drug-to-buddhism

I have no App ID yet. I set one up but I don't know how to link to the website. I googled and found a StackOverflow post related to this but the information there is outdated. I did add the fb:app_id value to my metas but to no avail. The warning is still there...

I've no idea why it's warning me that "The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.". There is only one mention of that tag on that page and it's quite explicit!

Comment: I just scraped the image URL directly once, and then your article again, and now the image shows up in the preview.

Comment: Hrmph. Maybe it was some temporary outage...